# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception After updating android studio to 3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

i have recently updated my android studio to version 3.2 since then i am receiving com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception exception 
i looked into solutions on stackoverflow but couldn't find the right one.

the drawable files as the error says are missing are already present there and the project was running fine before i updated the android studio to latest version 3.2.1

Error:

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  warn: removing resource com.example.mohit.chatapp:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:25: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:49: error: resource drawable/message_back (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/message_back) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:54: error: resource drawable/fb (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/fb) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_splash_screen.xml:10: error: resource drawable/ic_place_black_24dp (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_place_black_24dp) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:19: error: resource drawable/profilepicture (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/profilepicture) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:58: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:152: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:169: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Mohit\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1558dd943061657e6b17ed05cad5fd2f\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.mohit.chatapp\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
Output:  warn: removing resource com.example.mohit.chatapp:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:25: AAPT: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:49: AAPT: error: resource drawable/message_back (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/message_back) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:54: AAPT: error: resource drawable/fb (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/fb) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_splash_screen.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_place_black_24dp (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_place_black_24dp) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource drawable/profilepicture (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/profilepicture) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:58: AAPT: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:152: AAPT: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:169: AAPT: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.

E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.

error: failed linking file resources.
Command: C:\Users\Mohit\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1558dd943061657e6b17ed05cad5fd2f\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.mohit.chatapp\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2ErrorUtils.rewriteLinkException(Aapt2ErrorUtils.kt:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:527)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:275)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor224.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  warn: removing resource com.example.mohit.chatapp:string/com_facebook_loginview_logged_in_using_facebook_f1gender without required default value.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:25: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_chat_box.xml:49: error: resource drawable/message_back (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/message_back) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:54: error: resource drawable/fb (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/fb) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_splash_screen.xml:10: error: resource drawable/ic_place_black_24dp (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_place_black_24dp) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:19: error: resource drawable/profilepicture (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/profilepicture) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:58: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:152: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_profile.xml:169: error: resource drawable/white_view (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/white_view) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:3: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher_background (aka com.example.mohit.chatapp:drawable/ic_launcher_background) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Mohit\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1558dd943061657e6b17ed05cad5fd2f\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --proguard-main-dex\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\legacy_multidex_aapt_derived_proguard_rules\debug\processDebugResources\manifest_keep.txt\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.mohit.chatapp\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\andriodProjects\ChatApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonImpl.doLink(Aapt2DaemonImpl.kt:177)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Daemon.link(Aapt2Daemon.kt:103)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager$LeasedAaptDaemon.link(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:176)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:823)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:525)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Can anyone help ?

Comment: I think the latest one is `3.3.1`!

Comment: Your project is on E while the gradle cache and Android SDK are on C - could you try moving the project to C and see if that helps?

Comment: Also what version were you on before?